# What word(s) or term(s) best represent objects and phenomena that have not been experienced?

Tags: ontology

Using the top third of this graphic, what word(s) or term(s) is most recognized for representing REAL **objects**: 1) the objects themselves (not the phenomenal experience of them); 2) not known to be experienced by anyone ever (e.g. on a planet far far away); 3) not experienced by a specific person (like you or like me); and 4) experienced by someone unknown by a specific person (e.g. john experienced it but sue did not...or they experienced things like that in the middle ages but not today).  The same options apply for REAL **phenomena** (top right of the image below).

Secondarily (looking at the bottom half), do you agree each of the things one's mind does are 'phenomena' in-and-of themselves, and the objects stored from those phenomena are phenomenal objects, like knowledge, understanding, beliefs, values and abilities.  And is there a unique term for a **string-of-phenomenas** other than 'causal chain, and is there a unique term for a collection of related **phenomenal objects**?

Any sourcing for your answer is appreciated!

[image]

Comment: 1) objects are ... [objects](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/object/). 2) supposed or postulated objects. 3) Unknown to me. 4) Unknown to Sue.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA thanks for the 'simple' words and pointing me to the possible variations of the word 'object.  I also appreciate 'known' to parallel phenomenal (basic knowledge), but I believe we are in the minority.  With that version of known, unknown in front of Object and Phenomena work for 1) and 2), and I believe adding the type/classification in front of unknown might work for distinguishing 'who' has or has not experienced something, (personally, culturally, historically, scientifically, etc.).